# Trying to install scalatest on Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, scala, scalatest

I am trying to install [scalatest](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_eclipse) on Eclipse Juno. I already the Scala Plugin for eclipse version 2.1.0nightly-xxx installed (you have to used this one for Juno).  I got this from: http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-update-juno-master-29x/site.xml

I follow the instructions for [Scala IDE 2.1 Milestone 2](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_eclipse) and I get:

```
Scala Plugin 2.1.0.m3-2_09-201212171812-eb61d7f (org.scala-ide.sdt.core 2.1.0.m3-2_09-201212171812-eb61d7f) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.6.0,3.7.10)' but it could not be found
```

Googling this give me similar error messages for installing the Scala plugin for Eclipse on Juno which are fixed by installed from the nightly build. But, I get nothing for solving this issue for Scalatest.  Any tips?

Note: I already have eclipse JDT 3.8 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you should download the Java-Version of Eclipse. JDT is simply the "Java Development Tools" - the scala-ide won't run without JDT. Or you could install JDT afterwards in Help/Install New Software.

I've just seen - your scala-ide refers to the older Eclipse versions (3.7, 3.6)
There is an update-site for Scala 2.10 however for Juno:
Scala - http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/e38/scala210/dev/site/

OK - and the building of scalatest - did you use
`*To build for Scala IDE nightly for Scala 2.10 (Juno), use` ...  -Drepo.eclipse=http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/ -

Comment: OK, but scalatest should be available on the update site http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/e38/scala210/dev/site/ as well. You don't need to build the nightly build yourself, unless you want to debug or develop or fix bugs on it.

Comment: all worked thanks a million. I just uninstalled version I had and installed everything from version you suggested.

Comment: Cool - btw I added the link to the last Milestone with Scala 2.10 - which includes the latest language features (I wouldn't want to miss that). But the IDE is still buggy here and there. I read somewhere that it's (still) suggested to use JDK1.6 instead of 7 as your Java environment. So, if you encounter larger problems (especially when running the debugger) try it with the older JDK.

Comment: Scala has hight productivity but lower stability.

Comment: No, it is just the IDE and the tools around scala (also sbt) - not scala itself! The tools however did some mighty progress during the last year - and the IDE is really just a Milestone build!